# How can I use cl.exe in azure app service to compile c++ code and produce executable file

Tags: c++, azure, azure-web-app-service, cl

My app is hosted in azure app service and I want to compile c++ code and produce .exe file runtime using `Process` class in c#. I cannot install c++ compiler. However I see that there is installed visual studio in my azure app service and decided to use `cl.exe` which is in the following folder: `D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64_x86\cl.exe`.

When I run the following command in the azure app service console: `set PATH=%PATH%;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64_x86; & cl /EHsc test.cpp` test.exe is not produced and there are no errors.

Comment: Nasko, do you have a chance to check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C++ developer. But I've quickly searched and found the information below. I hope it is helpful.

1, You can't run cl.exe in prompt directly. Because it depends on a set of environment variables. Usually you need to run it from VS developer prompt or run a bat file shipped with VS to set up environment variables first. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019 for details.

The problem is there is no such bat file in Azure Web App environment.

2, In Azure Web App environment, the file system is special as the files are also shared with other users. You may be able to read system files, but you can only write to D:\home path. So you also need to chang the output file path to D:\Home . And if cl.exe need to write to some file in other folder, then it will fail.

The solution I can think of is you need to download the [standalone MSVC compiler tool](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) set and transfer it to your Azure Web App home folder. 
It contains CL.EXE file and the bat file we need. The files in D:\home folder are persistent in Azure. 
You can then follow the instruction [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019) to build with CL.EXE